# Spring JPA failing to create table with derby embedded database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, derby

I am developing a Rest API for fetching all topics from a database. I am using Spring Boot with Derby and using JPA to interact with derby. When Spring Boot application is started, the JPA is failing to create a table on derby and throwing an error.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table topic (id bigint not null, desc varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at io.carrotlabz.springproject.jpa.topicserver.TopicserverApplication.main(TopicserverApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 41.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 41.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatementOrSearchCondition(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

```
@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;

    public Topic() {

    }

    public Topic(Long id, String name, String desc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

```
public interface TopicRepo extends CrudRepository<Topic, Long> {
}
```

The first class is the entity class and second one is the repo class.

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue. A member object was desc which was coinciding with sql keyword desc. Changed it to description and worked finely.

Comment: Yes, `desc` is the SQL keyword for "descending", in sort ordering.

Comment: Had the exact same issue following JavaBrains' course. Good to see you've put this up here.